# Asp.net Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
    function iframeLoaded() {
        var iFrameID = document.getElementById('iframe_login');
        if (iFrameID) {
            // here you can meke the height, I delete it first, then I make it again
            iFrameID.height = "";
            iFrameID.height = iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
    }
```

This script is not working in Mozilla firefox but it works in chrome.

Answer (score 2):

use jquery, http://api.jquery.com/height/

```
 function iframeLoaded() {
        var iFrameID = $('#iframe_login');
        if (iFrameID) {
            iFrameID.height(...)
        }
    }
```

Comment: please tell me what type of changes i do on my code for run this code on mozilla